# How can I dynamically create variables base on JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## I have : external JSON file

```
{

    "A": {
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "problem_set": "Same",
        "start_time": "7/20/2015 10:00 am",
        "student_am": "9",
        "due_time": "7/20/2015 11:00 am",
        "submit": "9",
        "avg_score": "71",
        "danger": "0",
        "warning": "2",
        "success": "3"

    },

    "B": {
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "problem_set": "Not the same",
        "start_time": "6/19/2015 1:00 pm",
        "student_am": "23",
        "due_time": "6/19/2015 2:00 pm",
        "submit": "7",
        "avg_score": "82",
        "danger": "1",
        "warning": "2",
        "success": "2"

    },

    "C": {
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "problem_set": "Math",
        "start_time": "6/20/2015 2:00 pm",
        "student_am": "23",
        "due_time": "6/20/2015 3:00 pm",
        "submit": "3",
        "avg_score": "82",
        "danger": "0",
        "warning": "2",
        "success": "3"

    },

    "D": {
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "problem_set": "Anything",
        "start_time": "6/20/2015 7:00 am",
        "student_am": "25",
        "due_time": "6/20/2015 8:00 am",
        "submit": "9",
        "avg_score": "98",
        "danger": "1",
        "warning": "0",
        "success": "4"

    }
}
```

---

### I load them in using Ajax

```
$.ajax({

      url: basePath + "data-r.json",
      type: "GET",
      dataType : "json",

      success: function( data ) {

         google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

         function drawChart() {

           var options = {
            width: 160,
            height: 160,
            chartArea: {
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%"
            },


            colors: ['#F46E4E',  '#F9C262' , '#ADB55E',],
            legend: 'none',
            enableInteractivity: false,
            pieSliceText: 'none',

          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));



          for (var object in data) {

            var total = data[object].danger + data[object].warning + data[object].success ;
            var object = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Piechart', 'Number of Skills'],
            ['danger',  ( data[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
            ['warning', ( data[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
            ['success', ( data[object].success/total ) * 100  ],
            ]);

          }

      chart.draw(A, options);

    }
```

---

### I tried to create variables base on those data in my JSON, and I couldn't

```
for (var object in data) {

            var total = data[object].danger + data[object].warning + data[object].success ;
            var object = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Piechart', 'Number of Skills'],
            ['danger',  ( data[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
            ['warning', ( data[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
            ['success', ( data[object].success/total ) * 100  ],
            ]);

          }
```

It clearly failed on me.

and when I tried to draw out the first chart  `chart.draw(A, options);`

I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined

Comment: Why not `chart.draw(data.A, options);`? Doesn't seem like you need variables. It's possible to create them dynamically, but there's a cost that almost never needs to be incurred.

Comment: There is only a certain data that I want to retrieve from my JSON. - not all.

Comment: Will `data.A` grab the whole things ?

Comment: Right, and `data.A` only gives you that part of the JSON. It'll give you that sub-object only. Same thing that a variable would.

Comment: I have to try it. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Please follow up with the answer given below.

Comment: I got error. I think I need to create variables in order for Google chart to draw.

Comment: I highly doubt you need to have explicit variables, as they are just references to literal values. What is the new error that you're getting?